# cannot run JavaScript function from XSL

Tags: javascript, xslt

I have a form element in an XSL file. I want to have a JavaScript function in the same XSL file to enable the Submit button on checking a check box.

Here is the form -

```
<form action="NewUserNavigation" method="post" name="NewUserNavigationForm">
<input name="eventName" type="hidden" value="NewUserNavigationEvent"/>
<div class="sansIcon">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk" onClick="EnableSubmit()"><xsl:apply-templates   select="content[@name='chkbox']" mode="impl_expandContent"/></input>
                </div>
<div class="buttonBarPage">
<input name="Submit" class="primary" type="submit" value="Continue" disabled="true"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the XML conetent that it is reading -

```
<content name = "chkbox">
    Yes, I understand and agree to the T&C.
</content>
```

I am facing problem with the javascript, it gives error. I have put an alert to check if the function is being called on click of the checkbox.

here is the code I am using -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function EnableSubmit()
{
  alert("test");
  if(document.NewUserNavigationForm.chk.checked==true)
  {
    document.NewUserNavigationForm.Submit.disabled=false;
  }
  if(document.NewUserNavigationForm.chk.checked==false)
  {
    document.NewUserNavigationForm.Submit.enabled=false;
  }
}
</script>
```

I get this error....

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: illegal top-level element
```

Comment: There is no XSLT transformation provided, nor the result of the transformation is provided. Don't expect even the best mind-reader among us to help -- much better, *edit* the question and provide this missing, important information.

Answer (score 1):

The end tag should be `</script>` rather than `<script>`.

By the way, did you know that with Saxon-CE you can do this without any Javascript? You can then write template rules in the stylesheet that respond to user input (such as button clicks) and modify the HTML DOM in arbitrary ways, without having to use the Javascript DOM API.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript function needs to wrapped in a CDATA tag, as it is not valid XML. Anything that you wrap in CDATA will be output exactly as is to the file you are writing (ie, the html). So:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
function EnableSubmit()
{
  alert("test");
  if(document.NewUserNavigationForm.chk.checked==true)
  {
      document.NewUserNavigationForm.Submit.disabled=false;
    }
    if(document.NewUserNavigationForm.chk.checked==false)
    {
      document.NewUserNavigationForm.Submit.enabled=false;
    }
  }
]]><script>
```

Comment: There's no harm in wrapping it in CDATA, but in this case it doesn't help. There are no special characters in this code fragment that need escaping.

Comment: wrapping with CDATA did not help. I still get error org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: illegal top-level element

Comment: if i replace <script></script> with <xsl:script></xsl:script> where <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" > i do not get the error, and successfully render the page. But the problem still remain... the javascript function is not getting invoked at all. it shows "error on page" at the bottom of the browser.

Comment: @ASG: There is no `<xsl:script>` instruction in XSLT -- you may be using some vendor-supplied, proprietory extension element, which absolutely incorrectly resides in the XSLT namespace -- I strongly recommend *not* to use this -- as it may not work with other XSLT processors (browsers).

Comment: @ Dimitre.... here are the snippets that you had asked for. Can you help me with the code?